# WordPress multisite doesn't work with Google VM instance and Network Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set up a WordPress website with Multisite on Google Virtual Machine(Apache) using Network Loadbalancer with Google-managed SSL. It works fine with a normal Wordpress site with the Load balancer. But it doesn't work when I enable multi-site configuration on the wp-config.php file.

I am using Google Cloud Virtual Machine, Apache web server, and Load Balancer with Google Managed SSL

The error message is: no healthy upstream

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: WordPress is probably crashing. Look in the Apache and PHP logs for error messages indicating the problem. Update your question with details on the error.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your comment. I have logs. However, there are no logs related to this issue. The problem is when I try to enable multisite the Google Cloud load balancer shows the error message 'no healthy upstream'

Comment: Without details on the load balancer, Apache, and WordPress configuration, I can only guess. `no healthy upstream` means your instance is not responding to the load balancer. Clear the logs, make one request, and then review the logs. You are overlooking something.

Comment: Hi, I tried your methods, But seems it doesn't work. Even When I use my VM public IP the multisite works fine. At the same time If I visit my domain it doesn't work. Could you please share any referrals is how to set up, a Google Cloud VM with Load Balancer with WordPress multisite

Comment: Update your question with the requested details so that an answer can be created. Otherwise, your question is low quality and will probably be closed.